# GitHub page displays correctly locally, partially in HTML once pushed

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I'm having trouble with my GitHub site. It builds just fine locally, but I'm encountering lots of issues with functionality online. My repository is [here](https://github.com/capecchi/capecchi.github.io) and the site is http://www.williamcapecchi.com.
The images are not being displayed in the post list and clicking any post or project leads to the page being displayed in HTML and losing the stylesheet. The link should also take you to this [homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSJTo.png) (or by clicking my name or profile pic on the left of the screen the link actually takes you to) but this home screen is not working either. I've made sure my version of Jekyll is up to date, but I haven't changed anything recently and can't figure out where the problem is. I'm new to site building so I feel like it might be an obvious answer, but any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `href`s to your `main.css`, etc. with just `css/main.css`, just use a fullly qualified url using jeykl's `site.url` tag, such as `'{{ site.url }}/css/main.css'`

Comment: In my _includes head.html I now have '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.url }}">'. When I deliberately break the link (by trying to tell it to look in the wrong folder, it loads purely in HTML as expected. So it's getting the stylesheet information.
After some tinkering I've now created the issue where my post lists do not appear online (everything still looks fine locally).Why would my post-list.html layout work locally but not online?